# How do I launch a Word VBA Application from a Form (not a document)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a Word Application using VBA.  At present, I launch it from the IDE associated with a particular document.  When my app launches, I click a Command Button on a Form to begin processing my data.

Question: How do I launch this application directly from the Form?  Perhaps I can fashion my Word document to look like my Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a form to collect information from the user, you can run macros directly from Word. Go to the View Ribbon tab and click the Macros button on the far right (or press Alt-F8).